# How to wrap text away from the bullet?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, listitem, bulletedlist

Is there away to make the text wrap away from the bullet, like using `list-style-position: outside` but using my custom pseudo-element bullet instead?

```css
div {
  width: 250px
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul>li::before {
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "\2022";
  color: #fee100;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
    <li>VLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does not seem to be a duplicate; voting to reopen. The OP mentions that he cannot use `list-style-position` as the bullets are pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use absolute position instead of relative with negative values:

```css
div {
  width: 250px
}

ul {
  padding: 10px;
 list-style: none;
}

ul>li {
 position:relative;
}

ul>li::before {
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left:-15px;
  top:-10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  content: "\2022";
  color: #fee100;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</li>
    <li>VLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that worked but it might not work in all situations, like what if there was an image to the left of the list, then the bullets will float over the image. but anyway switching the `position: absolute ` is the key. Thank you

Comment: @Abdal you can consider adding padding-left to the li or the ul to avoid this and be sure the custom bullet remain in the container ;)

Comment: I added `padding-left` to the ul and worked perfect.